# want to read .eeg files with R

Tags: r

I have to analyze some EEG data (electroencephalography) on R using `eegkit` package.

The format of the files is `.eeg` . Anybody knows how to read those files with R?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the [Medical Image Analysis of CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MedicalImaging.html) they have a section about Electroencephalograph, suggesting [edfReader](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/edfReader/index.html) to read files

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `geteegdata` would do the job.

Here is more information on it:

***Usage***

```
geteegdata(indir,outdir=indir,cond=c("S1","S2m","S2n"),nt=NULL, filename="eegdata",filetype=c(".rda",".csv",".txt"))

Arguments
indir Input directory (containing EEG data source folders).
outdir Output directory (to save EEG data matrix file).
cond Condition to read-in: S1=single stimulus, S2m=two matching stimuli, S2n=two
non-matching stimuli.
nt Number of trials to read-in for each subject (default is all trials).
filename Name for EEG data matrix (default eegdata).
filetype Type of file to save (default is R data file .rda).
```

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eegkitdata/eegkitdata.pdf